# vb.net textbox that won't let me highlight text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, highlighting

I'm working on an upgrade of a VB6 winforms project to VB.Net 2.0.  On one form (and only this one form, out of about 25), my text boxes are acting odd.

When a user clicks into (focuses on) a textbox with a value in it, the cursor automatically goes to the beginning (left side) of the textbox and can only be moved with the keyboard arrow keys.  I can't re-position the cursor with the mouse, and I can't highlight a section of text with the mouse.

The text box is not readonly and is both visible and enabled.  In fact all settings are default as I've dragged out a new textbox and added it to the form and I get the same behavior.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would have to look at any events that are wired up for that TextBox.

Comment: Is it standard TextBox or a custom one? Check events, maybe there is code present preventing standard behaviour - Mouseclick, MouseDown, MousereUp events come to mind.

Comment: I used the test box that I dragged in as a litmus test.  There are no events other than setting the .text value in the form load event.  This is a standard, everyday text box, nothing special.

Comment: I'm getting closer.  It seems to have something to do with my loading form with a split container panel as its parent...

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is answer:
The startup form was set as an MdiContainer.  This form had a split panel container that held another form for Application controls in panel 1 and the working forms in panel 2.  When the working forms were loaded into panel 2, they weren't allowed to be top level as there was a .Parent attribute set to the split container panel 2.  For some reason, the highlighting of text in a text box is disallowed unless the textbox is on a top level form, and since we couldn't get the working form to top level, we couldn't highlight the text.  For reference, check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/175273/Text-controls-doesn-t-let-to-select-the-text-with) out.